# windowed-observable is not working in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, observable

I am working on react micro frontend app, I have a host with products and order modules, and I am sending data from products but in orders, I am not able to receive data using windowed-observable.

```
   Products:
    import { Observable } from 'windowed-observable';
    const observable = new Observable('products');
    observable.publish('Samsung');
    
    Orders:
    import { Observable } from 'windowed-observable';
    const observable = new Observable('products');
    observable.subscribe((product) => {
      console.log(product)
    })
```